# angular 2+ filtering 3 boolean values

Tags: angularjs, typescript

id like to make a filter for this object

```
    export interface Components {
    verbal: boolean;
    somatic: boolean;
    material: boolean;
    materialMaterial: string;
    materialCost?: number;
}
```

id like to have 3 outputs true, false and any or null for example:     verbal: true; somatic: false; material: null; will show all objects that have a verbal element do not have a somatic element and both material and not material elements. the only way I can think of doing this is to change the type. id like to know if this can be done without changing the type

Answer (score 0):

**These kind of case where `enum` is useful.**

You could create an `enum` like

```
enum ComponentValue{
  Allow=1,
  Ignore,
  DontCare
}
```

**And in your interface**

```
export interface Components {
verbal: ComponentValue;
somatic: ComponentValue;
material: ComponentValue;
materialMaterial: string;
materialCost?: number;
```

}

Comment: this is true, thank you. In the past I have done this without enum I just set the type to any (e.g old javascript) however an enum is a much better approach to the problem than "any" type. I was after a way that didn't involve changing the type, as this is not the first time I have come across this problem and would like to know if there is an industry stranded way of filtering a boolean value this way

Comment: @may19c19 , Hi I thought your problem was not able to identify 3 values out of the `boolean` type. But `enum` or `any` will solve the problem easily that you already know of . If you don't want to change the type then make the `boolean` types `nullable` that way you can pass `true` ,`false` or `null` . If any of these not solve your problem then what is the exact problem sir ? I didn't understand it.

Comment: I am trying to identify 3 values out of a boolean, I had come across this situation a number of times and my fist thought was to change the type but that felt like a work-around not a solution.

Comment: okay then just make it nullable will solve your problem right?